# Is there any way I can call child method from parent class?

Tags: oop, c++11, cocos2d-x

I am building a game for cocos2d-x and want to call child class method from parent class.

```
class Parent {
    *//do something
    //How can i call method from subchild class here?*
}

class Child : Parent {
    *//do something*
}

class SubChild : Child {
    void functionToBeCalledFromParent();
}
```

Comment: There is a simple way: Use a virtual-function in `Parent` overridden in `SubChild`.

Comment: There is a less simple way: Use CRTP

Answer (score 0):

> I am building a game for cocos2d-x and want to call child class method from parent class

You can 1) declare the function In parent and define it in the child or 2) define it in parent and override it (re-define it) in child.

Answer (score 0):

By using [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), your example

```
class Parent {
    void callSubclassFunction() {
        //How can i call method from subchild class here?
    }
}

class Child : Parent {
}

class SubChild : Child {
    void functionToBeCalledFromParent();
}
```

would turn into

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename TSubclass>
class Parent {
public:
    void callSubclassFunction() {
        static_cast<TSubclass*>(this)->functionToBeCalledFromParent();
    }
};

template <typename TSubclass>
class Child : public Parent<TSubclass> {
};

class SubChild : public Child<SubChild> {
public:
    void functionToBeCalledFromParent() {
        std::cout << "SubChild!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    SubChild child;
    child.callSubclassFunction();
}
```

[Runnable at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92a81e99339753df)

Passing `SubChild` as template parameter to `Child<>` works because the typename is valid as soon it's declared, which it is just in front of the inheritance list divider `:`.

Using `static_cast` to "downcast" in `Parent` is completely benign here. If the subclass doesn't define the function called in `Parent`, the compilation will just fail.

This technique is called *static* or *compile-time* polymorphism and it's what the ATL and WTL are built upon. The oppsosite and perhaps more conventional method would be *dynamic* or *runtime* polymorphism and it's what you get with virtual functions.